# If subsequent terms keep getting larger, does that mean no limit exists?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Take the following Taylor expansion:

$$ \dfrac{1}{1-x} =  1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots $$

This only holds for $ 0 \leq x < 1. $ Let's say you want to prove this doesn't hold for $x>1$.

You can say that $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ will become negative, and a sum of positive numbers can never have a negative sum.

Intuitively, I was also thinking that for $x>1$, each subsequent term in the Taylor expansion becomes larger, so you have no limit. But are there any counter examples, where subsequent terms get larger but there still is a finite limit? Also, if so, what would be a better way to state my conjecture in a way that IS correct?

Comment: It actually holds for $-1<x<1$.

Comment: But yes, at the very least, for $a_1+a_2+\cdots + a_n + \cdots$ to converge, you need $a_n\to 0$, so if $x\geq 1$ then $x^n$ does not converge to $0$.

Comment: Hint:
Just use the facts about radius of convergence. You will get all your doubts clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the for the $n$-th term $a_n$ of a series it is true that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \ne 0$ then the series does not converge. This is exactly what you intuitively suspected. It has been proven and is referred to as the *n-th term test for divergence*.

Answer (score 1):

If $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$.

That is a standard theorem found in first-year calculus texts and in every analysis text that deals with this topic.

Of course, you find things on the internet that say $1+2+3+4+\cdots=\dfrac{-1}{12}$ and the like, but those deal with different kinds of convergence from the one usually intended in the result you state.

Comment: Should be "those deal with different kinds of infinite summation," I think. It's not a type of convergence at all.

Comment: OK, "a different kind of convergence of series".

Answer (score 0):

I could have used the necessary condition to prove this, but here's a more direct proof, just for the sake of looking at things from a different prospective.
Given this series:
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{k} a_i\ \ , \ \ \mbox{ subject to:} \ \ \ \ 
a_n=f(n) \land 
\begin{cases} 
f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}\\
f(n+1)>f(n)>0
\end{cases}
$$
this implies:
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{k} a_i=\sum_{i = 1}^{k} f(i) \ge \sum_{i = 1}^{k} f(1) = k\cdot f(1) >0
$$
now suppose:
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{i = 1}^{k} a_i = \lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{i = 1}^{k} f(i) =  \hat a$$
that would imply that:
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}(k\cdot f(1)) = f(1)\cdot\lim_{k\to\infty}k
= \hat b \le \hat a $$

> which is obviously impossible because: 
>   $$
> f(1)\cdot\lim_{k\to\infty}k = +\infty
> $$
>   so we have that:
>   $$
> \sum_{i = 1}^{+\infty} a_i \ \ \ \mbox{ is a positively divergent series.} 
> $$